# ionic and angular function not returning value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I can't get the `addReservation` function to return any value.

in `reservations.page.ts` it returns an empty array when I log to the console.

```
userReservations: Reservation[];
private resSubscription: Subscription;
constructor(private resService: ReservationsService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.resSubscription =
        this.resService.reservations.subscribe(reservations => {
          console.log('reservations...', reservations);
          this.userReservations = reservations;
        });
      }
```

below is `reservations.service.ts` I can't get the reservations in the return statement to log any value so I'm guessing the issue may be there.

```
export class ReservationsService {
  private _reservations = new BehaviorSubject<Reservation[]>([]);

  constructor(private authentication: AuthenticationService) { }

  // return the parking space reservations
  get reservations() {
    return this._reservations.asObservable();
  }

  // create a reservation
  addReservation(
    parkingSpaceId: string,
    parkingSpaceTitle: string,
    url: string,
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    reservedDayCount: number,
    reservedFrom: Date,
    reservedTo: Date
  ) {
    const newReservation = new Reservation(
      Math.random().toString(),
      parkingSpaceId,
      this.authentication.userId,
      parkingSpaceTitle,
      url,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      reservedDayCount,
      reservedFrom,
      reservedTo
    );
    return this.reservations.pipe(
      take(1),
      tap(reservations => {
        console.log('return reservations...', reservations);
        this._reservations.next(reservations.concat(newReservation));
      })
    );
  }  
}
```

Comment: I would have to do `this.resService.reservations` in `reservations.page.ts` right?  using this.reservations I get property does not exist.

Comment: can you show where you use 'addReservation'?

Comment: something like this: https://dev.to/avatsaev/simple-state-management-in-angular-with-only-services-and-rxjs-41p8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `addReservation` function.

The way you have it, the tap will only execute if `addReservation` is subscribed to... which is wrong because that will result in an infinite loop.

The following link shows **how to use Rxjs exclusively to manage state within an Angular service, without having to store any local copies of the data**:

https://dev.to/avatsaev/simple-state-management-in-angular-with-only-services-and-rxjs-41p8

This is how you would apply the pattern to your ReservationsService:

```
export class ReservationsService {
   get reservations(): Reservation[] {
        return this._reservations.getValue();
   }

   private set reservations(val: Reservation[]) {
     this._reservations.next(val);
   }

   private _reservations = new BehaviorSubject<Reservation[]>([]);

   constructor(private authentication: AuthenticationService) { }

  // return the parking space reservations
  get reservations$() {
    return this._reservations.asObservable();
  }

  // create a reservation
  addReservation(
    parkingSpaceId: string,
    parkingSpaceTitle: string,
    url: string,
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    reservedDayCount: number,
    reservedFrom: Date,
    reservedTo: Date
  ) {
    const newReservation = new Reservation(
      Math.random().toString(),
      parkingSpaceId,
      this.authentication.userId,
      parkingSpaceTitle,
      url,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      reservedDayCount,
      reservedFrom,
      reservedTo
    );
    this.reservations = [
      ...this.reservations, 
      newReservation
    ];

  }  
}
```

Comment: if I do `this._reservations.next(this.reservations.concat(newReservation));` I get Property 'concat' does not exist on type 'Observable<Reservation[]>'

Comment: right... you need to store a local reference to your array

Comment: can you please give an example?